# action filter is firing but redirect isn't happening

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, action-filter

I found this code to catch when my session expires:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace SuburbanCustPortal.MiscClasses
{
    public class SessionExpireFilterAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute {

        public override void OnActionExecuting( ActionExecutingContext filterContext ) {
            HttpContext ctx = HttpContext.Current;

            // check if session is supported
            if ( ctx.Session != null ) {

                // check if a new session id was generated
                if ( ctx.Session.IsNewSession ) {

                    // If it says it is a new session, but an existing cookie exists, then it must
                    // have timed out
                    string sessionCookie = ctx.Request.Headers[ "Cookie" ];
                    if ( ( null != sessionCookie ) && ( sessionCookie.IndexOf ( "ASP.NET_SessionId" ) >= 0 ) ) 
                    {
                      ctx.Response.Redirect("~/Home/Login");
                    }
                }
            }

            base.OnActionExecuting ( filterContext );
        }
    }
}
```

It is firing without issue but the called action is still running it's course:

```
[Authorize]
[SessionExpireFilter]
public ActionResult PrePayment(PaymentModel.PrePayment model)
{
  if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Session[SessionEnums.CurrentAccountGuid.ToString()].ToString()))
  {
    return RedirectToAction("AddCustomer", "Customer");
  }

  if (TempData["ViewData"] != null)
  {
    ViewData = (ViewDataDictionary) TempData["ViewData"];
  }
```

...

`[SessionExpireFilter]` is running on this code but then it continues on with the rest of the method which causes issues because session is no longer valid. I get an error on the first line of `PrePayment` since it is returning.

Shouldn't the redirect prevent this from happening?

EDIT **

I made the changes suggested and now have:

namespace SuburbanCustPortal.MiscClasses
{
    public class SessionExpireFilterAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute {

```
    public override void OnActionExecuting( ActionExecutingContext filterContext ) 
    {
        HttpContext ctx = HttpContext.Current;

        // check if session is supported
        if ( ctx.Session != null ) {

            // check if a new session id was generated
            if ( ctx.Session.IsNewSession ) {

                // If it says it is a new session, but an existing cookie exists, then it must
                // have timed out
                string sessionCookie = ctx.Request.Headers[ "Cookie" ];
                if ( ( null != sessionCookie ) && ( sessionCookie.IndexOf ( "ASP.NET_SessionId" ) >= 0 ) ) 
                {
                  //ctx.Response.Redirect("~/Account/LogOn/");
                  filterContext.Result = new RedirectResult("~/Account/LogOn");
                  return;
                }
            }
        }

        base.OnActionExecuting ( filterContext );
    }
}
```

}

Prepayment is being called by AccountScreen and it seems that it is being reloaded after the return.

Comment: In every code path, base.OnActionExecuting is called. Have you tried returning immediately after setting the Response?

Comment: instead of running the `base.OnActionExecuting` ?

Comment: Yes. Edit: See @YairNevet answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this:

```
   filterContext.Result = new RedirectResult("~/Home/Login");
   return;
```

Instead of:

```
ctx.Response.Redirect("~/Home/Login");
```

Comment: any way that I can redirect this to a controller instead of a web page?

Comment: @ErocM In MVC there is no Web-Page. When you are specifying '~/Home/Login' it's equivalent to: Home Controller => Login Action (method).

Comment: I thought it was working but the account screen is being recalled. I have posted my changed code. AccountScreen is the originating form that calls PrePayment. It's reloading it...

Comment: @ErocM I guess you're working on forms-authentication mode so that it doesn't matter where you're redirecting the user to because in any case, if the user is not authenticated, he will be redirected to your default login/account action.

Comment: Wouldn't that be decided by this line:        routes.MapRoute("Default", "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                      new {controller = "Account", action = "Logon", id = UrlParameter.Optional});

Comment: @ErocM No, it will be decided by your web.config. for example: `<forms loginUrl="member_login.aspx" defaultUrl="index.aspx" />`. Read more at: [FormsAuthentication.LoginUrl Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.formsauthentication.loginurl.aspx)

Comment: ah the issue was in /account/logon it was checking to see if they were logged in and if so, it redirected them to the /account/AccountScreen. I forced the logout before the return.